# How can I trigger a lambda when a log group is created in cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I trigger a lambda when a log group is created in cloudwatch? What I am thinking the easiest way to do is to create a cloudwatch rule to send cloudtrail event to lambda. Is it reasonable to do? If yes, how can I filter out other events but only trigger lambda when a log group is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only event type supported by CloudWatch Events (CWE) for CW Logs (CWL) is:

```
AWS API Call via CloudTrail
```

Therefore, you can catch the events of interests when you enabled [CloudTrail (CT) trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-and-update-a-trail.html). Once enable, API events would be available in CWE. Then, you would have to [create CWE rule which captures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html) [CreateLogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogGroup.html) API call. The rule would trigger your lambda function.

An example CWE rule could be:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.logs"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "logs.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateLogGroup"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I did a test and when a Lambda function is run, it calls `CreateLogGroup`. This API call is displayed within CloudTrail, so you can trigger a Lambda function from that event via CloudWatch Event rules.

Comment: @marcin - how to enable CloudTrail to do this, within Cloudformation?

Comment: @Justin Please make SO question specific to your issue with your current template and any errors you are getting.

Comment: @marcin my apologies please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041842/getting-cloudwatch-to-send-createloggroup-messages-to-eventbridge if you have a moment